# Subset using minimum number of values positioned around maximum value

Tags: r, dplyr, subset

**Situation:** I have a list of data sets, collected by different loggers, like so:

```
df <- structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "logger1", class = "factor"), OriginalTraitValue = c(0.37968, 
                                                                                                                     0.455131, 0.606376, 0.910194, 1.19499, 1.55612, 1.91735, 2.35493, 
                                                                                                                     2.60147, 2.42803, 1.66277, 1.12656, 0.628537), Temp = c(11.7334, 
                                                                                                                                                                             14.627, 19.3428, 24.5959, 29.6344, 34.7809, 39.606, 44.5389, 
                                                                                                                                                                             49.7914, 54.8254, 59.6391, 64.6695, 69.7002)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                -13L))
```

---

**Task:** I only want to keep data sets that have a minimum of two recorded `Temp` values, before and after `max(OriginalTraitValue)`.

I hope this plot makes it clearer. Red = maximum value, Green = values required to keep a data set.

[image]

---

### Question

How do I do this in R, e.g. using `dplyr`?

I have managed to identify the `Temp` value corresponding to `max(OriginalTraitValue)` using `df$Temp[df$OriginalTraitValue == max(df$OriginalTraitValue)]`, but I'm struggling with the necessary position arguments to filter the data sets.

### EDIT

The example above represents a data set I would like to keep. The full data set looks something like this:

```
    df <- structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("logger1", "logger2", "logger3"
), class = "factor"), OriginalTraitValue = c(3.36e-11, 3.68e-11, 
5.12e-11, 6.24e-11, 6.72e-11, 8.64e-11, 1.04e-10, 1.1e-10, 1.18e-10, 
90.34189, 86.332214, 108.00114, 111.190155, 114.34427, 135.1673, 
139.18198, 142.76979, 145.09233, 0.002, 0.06, 0.07, 0.15, 0.17, 
0.17, 0.18, 0.18, 0.15, 0.07, 0.09), Temp = c(16, 18, 20, 22, 
24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 16.726307, 17.376368, 20.193129, 25.06135, 
25.060663, 29.875113, 29.924177, 30.422773, 34.417274, 10, 12.5, 
15, 18, 20, 22.5, 25, 27.5, 30, 32.5, 35)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-29L))

> summary(df)
       ID     OriginalTraitValue      Temp      
 logger1: 9   Min.   :  0.00     Min.   :10.00  
 logger2: 9   1st Qu.:  0.00     1st Qu.:18.00  
 logger3:11   Median :  0.15     Median :25.00  
              Mean   : 37.02     Mean   :23.90  
              3rd Qu.: 90.34     3rd Qu.:29.92  
              Max.   :145.09     Max.   :35.00
```

In this data set, I would only keep `ID` as `logger3`, since only `logger3` contains at least 2 values before and after `max(OriginalTraitValue)`.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I edited my question to make this more clear. The expected output is a code that will keep or drop an ID all together from the data frame, if less than 2 values before and after the max were collected (by one ID)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  slice(which.max(OriginalTraitValue) + -2:2) %>%
  filter(n() == 5)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Groups:   ID [1]
  ID      OriginalTraitValue  Temp
  <fct>                <dbl> <dbl>
1 logger1               1.92  39.6
2 logger1               2.35  44.5
3 logger1               2.60  49.8
4 logger1               2.43  54.8
5 logger1               1.66  59.6
```

If you'd like to filter the whole group and not just the 5 observations in questions, you could also do something like:

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(any(cumsum(row_number() %in% c(which.max(OriginalTraitValue) + -2:2)) == 5))
```

Comment: Thanks! I can use this to identify the `ID` I want, and then later subset the complete data frame.

Comment: You're welcome @Joris! See my edit, I've added a solution which would keep the complete data frame so you don't need additional subsetting.

Comment: Works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that with dplyr `filter`

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(abs(which(OriginalTraitValue == max(OriginalTraitValue)) - row_number()) <= 2)

  ID      OriginalTraitValue  Temp
  <fct>                <dbl> <dbl>
1 logger1               1.92  39.6
2 logger1               2.35  44.5
3 logger1               2.60  49.8
4 logger1               2.43  54.8
5 logger1               1.66  59.6
```

Comment: Great idea. Intuitive. +1

Comment: This will fail the condition `minimum 2 values before and after`. Try it on `structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 1L), .Label = "logger2", class = "factor"), 
    OriginalTraitValue = c(0.37968, 0.455131), Temp = c(11.7334, 
    14.627)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")`, it should remove the values but it'll keep them. Add something like `n() == 5` in the `filter`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I hadn't correctly specified my expected output. I think I would need to use this kind of syntax as a condition to keep or drop a specific ID.